# Access-Control-Allow-Origin for Magento 2 and ionic

Tags: ionic3, magento2

There are many questions about "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" which I applied in htaccess as follows

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

After applying that I am facing following error:

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XXX/rest/V1/categories/3357' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status."

I also applied following lines:

> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
>
> Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers
>   "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type"

Could you please help?

Comment: Have you checked if your webserver uses the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes it does. We have checked already.

Comment: Keep in mind that (at least) iOS in gernal does not allow requests using http due to security reasons. Have you tested over https?

Comment: It's in development server. So we did not implement https.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use https in development too, it will save you from many headaches.

Answer (score 3):

You can add below code to your Magento project .htaccess file, it will allow the API to be called from other origins.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "index.html" [R=200,E=API:1,PT]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Any help thanks - https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/317950/57334

Comment: Working. But why require to add RewriteCond? any idea.

Answer (score -1):

put the following code in your .htaccess

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH,
DELETE"

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

Comment: This looks more or less like the accepted answer and doesn't seem to add anything?

Comment: i have tried this solution and it works for me that's why i suggested